# Pset4 (More Comfortable) - Blur Issue

Tags: c, debugging, filter, cs50

I ran into trouble compiling my code as I get a segmentation fault error. I believe it is something to do with how I am trying to free image from heap and reassigning it to point to average. I would've thought that it would be fine since image will again be freed in filters.c based on the new address it is pointing to.

I did a debug50 and stepped through my code. I realized that when I did an reassignment where image was pointed to average, it does not transpire after the stack function blur. The address reverts back to image's original address. Is there any way around this?

Here is my code:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
 
    // Create a of the image array to store the average of the pixel
    RGBTRIPLE (*average)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
 
    // Iterate through each row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Iterate through each column
        // Also declare the sub row and col that will be determined based on current i,j
        for (int j = 0, x = 0, y = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Declare variable parameters to determine sub for loop width and height
            // Count is used to track division after sum is taken from surrounding pixels
            float count = 0.0;
            int boxh, boxw;
 
            // ====HORIZONTAL COMPONENT====
            // Check if current row at the first row. Set x = 0 and box height i + 1
            if ((i - 1) < 0)
            {
                x = i;
                boxh = i + 1;
            }
 
            // If current row is not at the boundary, set x to 1 row before and box height + 1
            else if ((i + 1) == height)
            {
                x = i - 1;
                boxh = i;
            }
 
            // If current row is the last row, set x to 1 row before and box height = i
            else
            {
                x = i - 1;
                boxh = i + 1;
            }
 
            // ====VERTICAL COMPONENT====
            // Check if current col at the first col. Set y = 0 and box height j + 1
            if ((j - 1) < 0)
            {
                y = j;
                boxw = j + 1;
 
            }
            // If current col is not at the boundary, set y to 1 col before and box height + 1
            else if ((j + 1) == width)
            {
                y = j - 1;
                boxw = j;
            }
 
            // If current col is the last col, set y to 1 col before and box height = j
            else
            {
                y = j - 1;
                boxw = j + 1;
            }
 
            // Iterate through subset box based on parameters determined above
            for (; x <= boxh; x++)
            {
                for (; y <= boxw; y++)
                {
                    // Take summation of each RBG value and store it in the current pixel on average array
                    average[i][j].rgbtRed += image[x][y].rgbtRed;
                    average[i][j].rgbtGreen += image[x][y].rgbtGreen;
                    average[i][j].rgbtBlue += image[x][y].rgbtBlue;
 
                    // Count number of pixels used
                    count++;
                }
            }
 
            // After summation is complete, divide sum of each RBG value and divide by count
            average[i][j].rgbtRed = round(average[i][j].rgbtRed / count);
            average[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(average[i][j].rgbtGreen / count);
            average[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(average[i][j].rgbtBlue / count);
 
        }
    }
 
    // Free current image array from heap
    free(image);
 
    // Set image pointer to average array
    image = average;
 
    return;
}
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
~/pset4/filter/ $ ./filter -b images/yard.bmp out.bmp 
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==661==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7fd256615010 (pc 0x7fd255674c3c bp 0x000000000708 sp 0x7ffc319b62e8 T661)
==661==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x7fd255674c3b  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x18ec3b)
    #1 0x7fd255571993  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x8b993)
    #2 0x7fd255565976  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x7f976)
    #3 0x423456  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x423456)
    #4 0x7fd255507b96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #5 0x402dd9  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x402dd9)
 
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==661==ABORTING
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think `image = newimage` does?

Comment: I thought it set the image (pointer) to address of what newimage is pointing to.

Comment: `image` is a parameter. The parameter is a local variable. When the function starts, it is initialized to the value the calling routine passed as an argument. `image = newImage` merely changes the value of the local variable. It does not change anything in the calling routine. You must find some other way to return a pointer or some other way to return the data in the image.

Comment: @Eric Oh ok. I thought it was declared as a pointer `RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width]`    and passed as such similar to how this swap function was implemented. `void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}`

Comment: That `swap` function does not swap the values of `a` and `b`. It swaps the things they point to.

Comment: If you do not know how to return a pointer to newly allocated memory and how to update it in the caller, then an alternative is just to use a local array inside the function for the temporary values, then, at the end of the routine, copy the contents of that array into the caller’s array. You will learn other solutions later.

Comment: I thought that since image was declared as a pointer, I was able to do it similarly as the swap function I pasted up top. I thought that the way that both `image` and `newImage` were declared were pointers. Am I misinterpreting it? I feel that I kind of get how pointers work and how you can interchangeable treat them like an array hence the reason why it was passed in the parameter of blur as an array rather than a pointer.

Comment: I have yet to implement the last function edges and was looking to do the same thing (i.e . image = newImage). Is there a way that I can set pointer to newly allocated memory or does it not work because of either how it was declared or how it is passed in through the parameters?

Comment: The swap function does not have `int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;`, and it would not work if it did. It does not and cannot swap `a` and `b` in the calling function. The swap function has `int tmp = *a; *a = *b; *b = tmp;`. That swaps **the things `a` and `b` point to**, not `a` and `b`. In `blur`, you cannot change the value of `image` in the caller. You can only change the things it points to. There are ways to give the caller new pointers, but that is not the point of this exercise. Just get the function working by changing the data that the caller’s `image` points to.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks so much for your patience and replies! I will go ahead and just change the data that caller's image in pointed to. I just wanted one more clarification to satisfy my curiosity. I believe that you mentioned that what I am trying to do is beyond the scope of this exercise. Is it safe to say then that the way that the parameters are setup to pass image in the function blur will not let me reassign what its pointing to? I do know that the constraints of this exercise does not allow me to change how the parameters are setup based on the prototypes in helpers.h.

Comment: Yes, if you cannot change the function declaration, there is no reasonable way to return a new address (pointer) to the calling function. Normally, returning a new address would be done either through a function return value or through a pointer-to-a-pointer that the caller passes. Each of those requires changing the function prototype. So it appears you are intended to change the data in place.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! I was wrestling with this for a few days trying to force it to work with how I wanted to implement it.